# How to pass imageView.image in dropbox upload file method

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I am trying to upload image from uiimagepicker It is returning image in imageview.

Now I want to upload this selected image to dropbox. How can I do this

my code is

```
- (IBAction)uploadButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [restClient uploadFile:@"Test.png" toPath:@"/" fromPath:imageview.image];

}
```

this is giving warning because It take **NSString** in **fromPath**:
How to pass image here with its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first need to save the image to the document directory, then all the function:

```
[restClient uploadFile:@"Test.png" toPath:@"/" fromPath:@"path/of/file/indocmentdirectory"];
```

Comment: Ok.Means I should  use UIImagePickercontrollersourcetypecamera and then save it to document directory?

Comment: I'd suggest you save the image to the temporary directory (using NSTemporaryDirectory() ) and not the documents directory, but otherwise I agree with rckoenes' answer.  The problem with saving to the documents directory is if your app supports iTunes File Sharing, you'd have these temporary image files in there.

Comment: @rekle and @rckoenes I will try both..Another problem is: I used restClient loadFile to download file from dropbox and it is working properly .but when I tried it to download folder it is giving error 404